# where to find general tutorials about minimal house beat programming?

Tags: programming

i've searched the net for good tutorials about minimal house beat programming.
there's a lot tuts @ youtube but nothing specific for beat programming.

any ideas?

thx

Answer (score 2):

Look for tutorials for your tools of choice (MPC, Ableton, whatever).  Once you understand how to use those, it should be clear how to program to the style of your choosing.  There are a number of books on drum machine programming with examples for particular styles, which is also a good starting point.

If you have access to some genre-specific loop libraries, some of those include example MIDI sequences to show how the beat structures work.  Study those to figure out why the style you like works.